# How to convert [8]*uint8 to **uint8

Tags: c, go, cgo

Background: using cgo to call C functions from Golang.

I want to use a C function which has this signature: int swr_convert(struct SwrContext *s, uint8_t **out, int out_count, const uint8_t **in , int in_count);

I need to pass data []*uint8 from func Data(f *Frame) (data [8]*uint8) to func (s *Context) SwrConvert(out **uint8, oc int, in **uint8, ic int) int

```golang
// ...

func Data(f *Frame) (data [8]*uint8) {
    for i := range data {
        data[i] = (*uint8)(f.data[i])
    }
    return
}

// ...

//Core conversion functions. Convert audio
func (s *Context) SwrConvert(out **uint8, oc int, in **uint8, ic int) int {
    return int(C.swr_convert((*C.struct_SwrContext)(s), (**C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(out)), C.int(oc), (**C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(in)), C.int(ic)))
}
```

Comment: `&(data[0])` is the address.

Comment: Note that a C function *type signature* does not always tell you everything you need to know. In particular, when a type signature calls for a pointer, you cannot tell from this alone whether you are to pass a pointer to some actual variable that the callee will *fill in*, or whether you are to pass a pointer to some already-filled-in actual variable that the callee will *use*. Moreover, when you are to pass both a pointer and a size, you don't know whether you're to pass a pointer to a single variable, or to N adjacent variables, so that the callee can access and/or fill-in an array.

Comment: I don't know Go, does `data [8]*uint8` mean an array of pointers to uint8t or a pointer to an array of uint8? In case of the former, `uint8_t**` works in C. In case of the latter, you will need the C function to have a `uint8_t (*)[8]` parameter, or optionally the equivalent `uint8_t [][8]`.

Comment: Go type definitions are read simply left-to-right, so [8]*uint8 means an array of pointers